# User Input to Url using Async Task

Tags: android, android-asynctask, user-input

I'm currently using XMLPullParser to parse a page from a train station API. I'm doing this using Async task as to keep up with the newer versions of android.

Currently I have hardcoded the XML string into the class and the results display out in a listview.

However, I am having trouble appending the baseURL to add a user inputted query to the end of it. I had no trouble doing this before using Async Tasks using code along these lines:

```
    public void StationDetails(){
    //--- Search button ---
    Button btnSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    btnSearch.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    //--- EditText View ---
    EditText input = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.inputStation);
    StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(baseURL);
    URL.append(input);
    String fullURL = URL.toString();
          }
      });
       }
```

But I cannot relate this into the Async Method. I can't seem to find anything online and would really appreciate anyones help in this matter.

Here is the class with the hardcodes string:

```
public class Realtime extends Activity {

// Irish Rail Site URL
private static final String baseURL =  "http://api.irishrail.ie/realtime/realtime.asmx/getStationDataByNameXML?StationDesc=Malahide";
// XML TAG Name
private static final String TAG_ITEM = "objStationData";
private static final String TAG_ORIGIN = "Origin";
private static final String TAG_DEST = "Destination";
private static final String TAG_SCHARR = "Scharrival";
private static final String TAG_EXPARR = "Exparrival";
private static final String TAG_DIRECT = "Direction";
private static final String TAG_STAT = "Status";
private static final String TAG_TRAINTYPE = "Traintype";

private RealtimeListviewAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stations_realtime_layout);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    mAdapter = new RealtimeListviewAdapter(this);
    // set adapter
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    // use AsyncTask to parse the URL data
    ParseTask task = new ParseTask(this);
    task.execute(baseURL);

    // --- Register the list view for long press menu options
    registerForContextMenu(listView);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private class ParseTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<StationDetails>> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    public ParseTask(Context c) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Station Info...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<StationDetails> doInBackground(String... params) {
        String strUrl = params[0];
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);
            httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            httpConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            httpConnection.connect();
            int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                is = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                return parseNews(is);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO
        } finally {
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (httpConnection != null) {
                httpConnection.disconnect();
                httpConnection = null;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<StationDetails> result) {
        // set the result
        mAdapter.setData(result);
        // notify to refresh
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Close the progress dialog
        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}

private ArrayList<StationDetails> parseNews(InputStream in)
        throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
    ArrayList<StationDetails> newsList = new ArrayList<StationDetails>();
    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    XmlPullParser pullParser = factory.newPullParser();
    pullParser.setInput(in, "UTF-8");
    int eventType = pullParser.getEventType();
    StationDetails item = null;
    while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
        String tagName;

        if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
            tagName = pullParser.getName();
            if (tagName.equals(TAG_ITEM)) {
                item = new StationDetails();
            } else if (tagName.equals(TAG_ORIGIN)) {
                if (item != null) {
                    item.mOrigin = pullParser.nextText();
                }

            } else if (tagName.equals(TAG_DEST)) {
                if (item != null) {
                    item.mDestination = pullParser.nextText();
                }
            } else if (tagName.equals(TAG_SCHARR)) {
                if (item != null) {
                    item.mSchArrival = pullParser.nextText();
                }
            } else if (tagName.equals(TAG_EXPARR)) {
                if (item != null) {
                    item.mExpArrival = pullParser.nextText();
                }
            } else if (tagName.equals(TAG_DIRECT)) {
                if (item != null) {
                    item.mDirection = pullParser.nextText();
                }
            } else if (tagName.equals(TAG_STAT)) {
                if (item != null) {
                    item.mStatus = pullParser.nextText();
                }
            }

        } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
            tagName = pullParser.getName();
            if (tagName.equals(TAG_ITEM)) {
                newsList.add(item);
                item = null;

            }
        }
        eventType = pullParser.next();
    }
    return newsList;
}
```

**EDIT** UPDATE

Ok I put the stringbuilder for the fullURL in an onClickListener for a button. Now what I want is to execute the task when the button is clicked. I moved the parsetask task, .excute etc into this clickListener. However this gives me an error saying that the View.OnClickListener for realtime is undefined, i follow the quick fixes, but then when running the porject I get an error in the logcat saying cannot be cast to android.content.Context.

Heres a snippet of what the code looks like now after the quick fix

```
searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Append user input to baseURL
            StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(baseURL);
            URL.append(userInput);
            String fullURL = URL.toString();

            // use AsyncTask to parse the URL data
            ParseTask task = new ParseTask(this);
            task.execute(fullURL);
        }
    });

public ParseTask(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog((Context) onClickListener);
    }
```

and my logcat:

[image]

I still can't figure this out and anybodys help would be very welcom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK problem solved.

What happened was I wasn't taking the userinput and appending it to the URL properly. Love how things are so simple some times. And I also used Realtime.this as Gleb suggested. Thanks for your help. Heres the code in the onClickListener that works...

```
searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        private String userInput;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            mAdapter = new RealtimeListviewAdapter(Realtime.this);
            //set adapter
            listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(baseURL);
            etStation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputStation);
            userInput = etStation.getText().toString();
            URL.append(userInput);
            String fullURL = URL.toString();
            //use AsyncTask to parse the RSS data
            ParseTask task = new ParseTask(Realtime.this);
            task.execute(fullURL);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you just send the full URL to the AsyncTask? Would look something like:

```
StringBuilder URL = new StringBuilder(baseURL);
URL.append(input);
String fullURL = URL.toString();// use AsyncTask to parse the URL data
ParseTask task = new ParseTask(this);
task.execute(fullURL);
```

Comment: I had tried putting that in the onCreate method a while back and it gives me a: The constructor Realtime.ParseTask(new View.OnClickListener(){}) is undefined error. I try the two quick fixes it gives to change or create constructor, but then when i run the app i get no response

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct Context to your ParseTask? Check this one out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9506778/progressdialog-using-asynctask-producing-constructor-undefined-error

Comment: Yeah I'm almost positive I am, as you can see my parsetask method has (Context c) which is used with dialog and then onPreExecute(). would building the string in either of these methods be of any help?

Comment: You are having a class cast exception. You are not passing context correctly. Have a look at this line: ParseTask task = new ParseTask(this); notice that you are NOT passing Context, you are passing Listener object reference. Try Realtime.this instead, if the snippet is located at Realtime class. Anyway, pass correct pointer to the constructor.

Comment: Ok I used Realtime.this instead as realtime is my class, no errors, runs fine, but now the results don't print out whatsoever, my dialog loads but then nothing, is there another piece of code I need to add in as a result of changing? thanks for your help

Comment: At your onPostExecute() check that you are getting data from result. You can also try to call invalidateViews() on your list adapter, or even call setAdapter() again.

Comment: In my onPostExecute I'm using mAdapter to setData(Result); tried putting mAdapter = new RealtimeListviewAdapter(this); into my onCreate and changing the context to realtime.this and the same thing, no errors but no results